# sharepoint - accidentally removed(not deleted) a column from a list view

Tags: sharepoint, filter, sharepoint-list

I tried modifying a view and unchecked the display for a column. Problem was that, this column 'Project No' was part of a filter.

So there is 200 site pages (dont ask me why!) which was refering to this particular view and once I unchecked that field from the display, it reset all the 200 page views.. so now all the 200 pages do not have the 'project no' filter..

Is there a way to put the filter back on, without going to all 200 site pages and editing the webpart and put the filter back on ?

thanks in advance...

Comment: Strange; that shouldn't happen. Each list view web part is treated as its own view, with its own configuration of columns to sort/filter/display, and should not be affected by changes made in other views, even if it was originally copied from some other list view. What version of SharePoint are you on?

Comment: sharepoint 2013. the display column was removed from the parent list, which was used in 200 odd site pages, which had a filter set on the list to display site specific info from that parent list..